# What is the simplest way of parsing C++ source code (extracting meta-info) in Java?

Tags: java, c++, parsing, compiler-construction

I need to extract classes, methods and parameters from *.c/*.cpp files in Java code.

I've reviewed:

- **Antlr** (can't find any ready c++ grammar for Java target),
- **gccxml** (probably works but i can't test on windows),
- **clang** (seems to be too large for this task), but none of them are good enough (or too giant for this task).

What approach is recommended?

Small libs without external dependencies are appreciated.

Comment: working on ctags output can be a good solution

Comment: Clang is really easy to use. Take a look at Python bindings to libclang for example.

Comment: yes, i know it's very good and user-friendly, but it seems to be too large for this task. BTW how can it be used in order to extract meta-data only?

Comment: I think “too large for the task” is incorrect: anything smaller than libclang *will not help you*. The current version of C++ has such a complex grammar that even just parsing function headers is a complex task that *requires a big library*. Use libclang.

Comment: okay, if the code is expected to be not very complex, can i use any lightweight tool or lib? i agree to have exceptions or incorrect result in complex case.

Comment: Take a look at the examples: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/ - I doubt any more "lightweight" tool will be any easier than that.

Comment: I've found java-bindings, but it's pretty difficult to make them working: https://github.com/pkukielka/jclang

Comment: It is a trivial plain C API, should be easy to wrap into JNI (or just run a Python process, if your environment allows it). You do not need full bindings.

Comment: Existing java-bindings use jna to create wrappers automatically and C API does not seem to be simple

Comment: I don't think there's an ANTLR solution; the ANTLR site has an incomplete (as of 2005 or so) grammar that was abandoned by its author and has never AFAIK seen serious usage.  GCCXML should work find under Windows.  Clang certainly should work, and it isn't any smaller than GCCXML which includes the GCC compiler as a component. You can't avoid the essential complexity; C++ is big and complicated, so tools that can process it are, too.  There's the Eclipse CDT, but I don't know if it is name and type accurate.  There are also commercial solutions.